# HowTo: Capture SOAP Specific Response in PHP

Tags: php, soap

How can i display in php the `firstName`, `lastName` and `targetName` from a SOAP Response. I already tried to change the `echo $response;` to:

```
echo $response->FindPersonsResponse->return->matchingPersons->person->targetName;
```

Or:

`echo $response->getElementsByTagName('firstName')->length;`

Or:

`echo $response->getElementsByTagName('firstName')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

But none are working.

I am new to SOAP or REST.
Thank you for your assistance.

Here is my SOAP Request:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/webservices/schema#5.5.47">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <sch:FindPersons>
     <sch:user>soaptest</sch:user>
     <sch:password>soaptest</sch:password>
     <sch:clientTimestamp></sch:clientTimestamp>
     <sch:clientIP></sch:clientIP>
     <sch:clientOSUser></sch:clientOSUser>
     <sch:company></sch:company>
     <sch:searchParameters>
        <sch:targetName>sandieax</sch:targetName>
     </sch:searchParameters>
    </sch:FindPersons>
</x:Body>
```

Here is my SOAP Response:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:FindPersonsResponse xmlns:ns="http://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/webservices/schema#5.5.47">
            <ns:return type="com.invoqsystems.apex.web.soap.FindPersonsReturn">
                <ns:matchingPersons>
                    <ns:person>
                        <ns:firstName>Aris</ns:firstName>
                        <ns:lastName>Sandiego</ns:lastName>
                        <ns:targetName>sandieax</ns:targetName>
                    </ns:person>
                </ns:matchingPersons>
                <ns:serverTimestamp>16/12/2015 11:51:42 AM</ns:serverTimestamp>
                <ns:status>OK</ns:status>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:FindPersonsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's my php file:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<x:Envelope xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:sch=\"http://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/",/webservices/schema#5.5.47\">\n    <x:Header/>\n    <x:Body>\n        <sch:FindPersons>\n         <sch:user>soaptest</sch:user>\n         <sch:password>soaptest</sch:password>\n         <sch:clientTimestamp></sch:clientTimestamp>\n         <sch:clientIP></sch:clientIP>\n         <sch:clientOSUser></sch:clientOSUser>\n         <sch:company></sch:company>\n         <sch:searchParameters>\n            <sch:targetName>sandieax</sch:targetName>\n         </sch:searchParameters>\n        </sch:FindPersons>\n    </x:Body>\n</x:Envelope>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: text/xml"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

EDITED:

Ok so i finally got it to capture either firstname, lastname or targetname.
The next problem is how can i display all results and not just the first result?

```
<?php
$data = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:sch=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/webservices/schema#5.5.47\">\r\n   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n   <soapenv:Body>\r\n      <sch:FindPersons>\r\n         <sch:user>soaptest</sch:user>\r\n         <sch:password>soaptest</sch:password>\r\n         <sch:clientTimestamp/>\r\n         <sch:clientIP/>\r\n         <sch:clientOSUser/>\r\n         <sch:company/>\r\n         <sch:searchParameters>\r\n            <sch:targetName></sch:targetName>\r\n         </sch:searchParameters>\r\n      </sch:FindPersons>\r\n   </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://wsdlurl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length: " . strlen($data)));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = DOMDocument::loadXml($output);
$value = $response->getElementsByTagName('targetName')->item(0)->textContent;
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.

```
$response = DOMDocument::loadXml($output);
$x = 0;

do {
$targetName = $response->getElementsByTagName('targetName')->item($x)->textContent;
$firstName = $response->getElementsByTagName('firstName')->item($x)->textContent;
$lastName = $response->getElementsByTagName('lastName')->item($x)->textContent;
$result = count($targetName);
echo "[" . $targetName . "] -- " . $firstName . " " . $lastName . "<br>";
$x++;
} while ($result != 0);
```